# Run Symfony 3 without cache when predis is down

Tags: php, caching, redis, symfony

In my symfony project i use the predis package to connect with redis;
In my config.yml :

```
doctrine_cache:
 providers:
  redis_cache:
    predis:
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 6379
```

In my config_dev.yml :

```
doctrine_cache:
 providers:
  redis_cache:
    type: array
```

This works fine,
However, when the redis server is down, my production doesnt work either.

Is there a way for me to go through redis, but when the connection fails just act like there is no caching, just like in dev?

Thanks in advance, let me know if i need to clarify my question more.

Comment: Yes, you need to write your own cache provier based on the predis provider, which will use fallback strategy if redis is down. But, honestly, it looks wired. If you use redis as a cache server you should do something to it so it won't stop every time.

Comment: sounds sensible. thanks for your response